# HTML No puedo poner icono

Tags: html, html5

Estoy hace media hora intentando entender que pasa, por qué no se visualiza el icono en la página?? Ya convertí la imagen a ICO acá https://convertico.com/jpg-to-ico/ Y sigue sin funcionar, alguien q me ayude por favorrr, gracias

[image: Imagen de Atom]

[image: Imagen de icono]

```
<?php
    include_once "include/header.php";
    include_once "include/estilos.css"; ?>
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DEP</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/iidd.ico">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <img src="img/iidd.jpg">
          <h1 id="Texto">Hola</h1>
        <?php
        include_once "include/footer.php";
        ?>
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: en que ubicación tienes tu pagina y en cual el icono, eso debes especificarlo.

Comment: ¿y porque dices que no funciona? Suponiendo que las rutas estan bien, ¿donde esperar verlo?  De momento tan solo lo has puesto en el link icon del header, pero quizás, para verlo en tu navegador, necesitarás limpiar tu cache, o bien probar otro navgador que aun no haya vistiado esa url, o bien incluirla en favoritos para que aparezca correcatamente, o bien suprimirla primero de allí y despues incluirla de nuevo.  Eso si la ruta es correcta, claro. Para comprobar la ruta tan solo ves a `dominio.com/¿ruta?/img/iidd.ico` y alli deberia salirte algo y no un error 404

Comment: @masterguru Mira la actualización de la publicación, adjunto imágenes más claras para ver si me podrían ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: @Jorgesys Mira la actualización de la publicación, adjunto imágenes más claras para ver si me podrían ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) Asegurate que esta url se abre bien y sale la imagen: `tudominio.com/dep/img/iidd.ico` o bien esta: `tudominio.com/img/iidd.ico` ... 2) Agrega ambas referencias con el type correcto en el head, es decir: `<link rel="icon" href="img/iidd.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` y  `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/iidd.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` a ver si asi primero llegas a ella y la ves, y segundo, a ver si funciona

Comment: @masterguru Sigue sin andar, no se q será, no será que utilizo es Xampp como servidor?? O algo por el estilo?? Es muy raro la verdad

Comment: Pero a ver, "sigue sin andar" no me ayuda a ayudarte... ¿que has hecho?  ¿que te ha dado la url esa de `tudominio.com/dep/img/iidd.ico` o bien la otra?  Es que no me dices que has hecho y los resultados o errores que has obtenido, y asi no se como esperas que te ayude

Comment: @masterguru Me sigue sin andar luego de colocar el <link rel="icon" href="img/iidd.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> y <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/iidd.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> Juntos, separados, al mismo tiempo, uno a la vez, y luego el tudominio.com/dep/img/iidd.ico Me abre la imagen, no da error, es muy raro, que sea en php dudo que tenga que ver, y que sea con Xampp tampoco

Comment: Vale, vamos avanzando, por fin me has confirmado que te abre la imagen :-)  Eso era importante... ahora toca saber si es un .ico correcto o no... ¿que tamaño tiene?  Yo los pongo de 144x144 y normalmente los denomino `favicon.ico` y los dejo en la raiz de la web, porque es lo que buscan los navegadores cuando no saben donde buscar.

Comment: Si me dices tu url lo miro in situ, pues tengo curiosidad, pero luego borrala de los comentarios (cuando la tenga vista, claro)

Comment: @masterguru el problema es q no tengo dominio aún, estoy con mi dominio local de xampp, soy muy nuevo en esto, hay alguna otra forma de mostrarte??

Comment: No creo, tampoco es plan de acceder remotamente a tu escritorio para verlo, asi que nada.  Yo de ti haria un ultimo intento, limpiando la cache de tu navegador para esa pagina, y ver si asi aparece el icono. Para ello tan solo debes mantener pulsada la tecla SHIFT mientras le das al boton "refrescar" de tu navegador para que recarge la página. Eso se salta lo que tengas en cache y lo va a buscar nuevamente, y quizas asi llegues a ver el icono de marras. Y hazlo cada vez que hagas un cambio y tengas que refrescar la página para verlos.

Comment: @masterguru Muchas gracias amigo, y perdon x quitarte tiempo, si lo soluciono te mando que era si queres así no te quedas con la duda jajajajaja

Comment: Si, déjalo dicho por aqui, asi lo veré :-)  saludos

Comment: @masterguru Logré solucionarlo, no se xq si ya habia hecho esto no me funcionaba, el problema era el header de php, pero esto ya lo habia probado antes (Borrando los includes) Y no me funcionaba, me funcionó cuando, en vez de usar una extensión ico, use una png, sin embargo, volví a utilizar la ico y anduvo, no se que habrá sido, mi solución fue mover el include/header.php al body, dentro de una etiqueta <header> </header> Dentro del header solo había listas, 2 imágenes y un par de hrefs, y poco más

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo, no se xq si ya habia hecho esto no me funcionaba, el problema era el header de php, pero esto ya lo habia probado antes (Borrando los includes) Y no me funcionaba, me funcionó cuando, en vez de usar una extensión ico, use una png, sin embargo, volví a utilizar la ico y anduvo, no se que habrá sido, mi solución fue mover el include/header.php al body, dentro de una etiqueta   Dentro del header solo había listas, 2 imágenes y un par de hrefs, y poco más

```
    <?php include_once "include/estilos.css"; ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DEP</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/iidd.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <?php include_once "include/header.php";?>
    </header>
    <img src="img/iidd.jpg" width=100%;>
    <?php
    include_once "include/footer.php";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pues tal como lo cuentas podria haber sido la cache del navegador, y al forzar lo del png eliminastes la del ico, y al volver a ponerla la cargo bien... es lo unico que le veo sentido, porque a todo lo otro que cuentas no :-)  Me alegro que te haya funcionado finalmente. Saludos!